# Is it possible to find which user created an account?

Tags: 7, users

I currently have a Drupal 7 site set up to allow users with the *Doctor* role to create users with the *Patient* role, via admin/people/create.

Does Drupal store data about which user created a specific account? If the answer is *yes*, how can I display this information in a view?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom module for this.

- First you have to add a user field here *admin/config/people/accounts/fields*. Add a field that will check whether the user has been created by user with role "doctor". A *boolean* field would suffice. Mark the field as **non-mandatory**
- Create a custom module. This module will provide an interface that only the users with role "doctor" can access. In the interface provide a button, clicking that button will create user with role "patient", also flag the field you created above.
- Now in views create a page or block that will display the users, in the filter criteria of the view check whether the boolean field is flagged for that user.

Answer (score 0):

On admin/reports/dblog, if you filter the log messages by type, and select "user" as log type, you see who created a user.

- The "Message" column will contain a message starting with "New User"
- The "User" column will contain a link to the user account of who created the user, or it will not contain a link when the user has not been created from a logged-in user

> [image: created from a logged-in user]

> [image: created from an anonymous user]

The same is true for who deleted a user account, as visible in the first screenshot.